# External script for account using pam_exec for openssh

Tags: linux, bash, security, ssh, openssh

I have a PHP application, with Usernames and Public SSH Keys in it. I would like to use these accounts as the user back end of openssh.

I think I need to use pam_exec and a PHP/Bash script. I've written a php script that I can execute at CLI (The shebang sets an env of php executable). If I need to wrap this in a bash script instead to access environment variables I can do that. The script currently takes a username as its first and only parameter like so:

```
/opt/scripts/my-auth-script.php user_to_look_for
```

The script will exit zero on success (the user exists) or exit 1 if not. It currently echoes OK or Failed also but I can easily turn that off.

So, my question is, how do I have pam_exec call my script to look for user accounts, before looking on the actual host system for user accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working. The way to do this is to set the AuthorizedKeysCommand and AuthorisedKeyUser settings of openssh in sshd_config. There is a caveat, the reason that github and others provide ssh as a service through a single login user shared among customers is that the user being called must be resolvable by the system being logged into, so they muxt exist locally, or the user db must be connected to a remote source like LDAP, which would also then have to be integrated into the application.

The way to get around this though, is that the AuthorizedKeyCommand can take parameters, %u for username, and also in this case %k for key or %f for sha256 fingerprint of the key. Then, that script can ignore the generic username it was given, and then just check the database for a match for the key or fingerprint. If we find it, we have the user for that key and successful authentication. If not we dont.